# Luggage storage in Boston

Tags: usa, luggage-storage, boston, massachusetts

According to [this source](https://www.boston-discovery-guide.com/boston-luggage-lockers.html), there are at least three luggage storage options at South Station. But it looks like all of them close at 8PM or earlier (on weekdays). Are there any places that store luggage until 10PM or so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn’t find any luggage storage in the station. There is an alternative 24/7 luggage storage facility less than a 10 minute walk away.

You can find a link here:

- https://stasher.com/luggage-storage/boston